# How to show the marked icon in photo in C# ( visual studio 2013)?

Tags: c#

The marked icon isn't shown with me:

[image]

I have "using System.Data.SqlClient;"
and the reference of (System.Data) is added also.

But I want this Icon (marked by red rectangle at photo) to be shown.

Comment: I think that lighbulb is from [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), which is paid extension for VS

Comment: I have something very similar in VS2017, without Resharper (VS is slowly 'borrowing' some of R#s features). Try pressing **Ctrl-.** (ctrl-period) with the blinking cursor inside the keyword; but I expect that VS2013 has much less options there compared to VS2017. So you might want to upgrade - recommended!

Comment: I tried it @peter B

Comment: ok i under stand point of Proper casing 
as c# is case sensitive

Comment: A tip, you might want to clarify or rephrase the question a little to avoid it from being closed as "Unclear what you are asking".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact class name is `SqlCommand`. C# is case-sensitive, so be aware of proper casing! VS may help fix casing issues using the hotkey Ctrl-Spacebar.

Comment: Error 1 Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement E:\INTAKE 38\4-OOP\Assignments\LOVE\ado lecture\ado lecture\Program.cs 15 13 ado lecture

Comment: That new error seems unrelated to the original question. Please post a new question with sufficient details. If my answer helped for the original question then please Accept it.